# Installing Sharepoint server with shared Minrole

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

So I am a bit confused about SharePoint server deployment. Let me give a run down of how I want the installation to be. 
We have about 6 servers with shared minroles and below is the plan on how we want it to be setup.

2 web front-end/distributed cache server
2 Application/search servers
2 db servers.
1 custom server
Also looking at setting up a load balancer for the 2 front-end servers.

My question is this, do I have to install SharePoint server software in all the servers in other to select their roles? I'm confused about that part.

If thats the case how do i go about the deployment really. Confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to install SharePoint SharePoint server software in all the servers.

First, you need to Create and configure the farm on the application servers. After creating the farm, you can add the servers to the farm. The below article would help you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/multiple-servers-for-a-three-tier-farm

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/add-web-or-application-server-to-the-farm

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/add-a-database-server-to-an-existing-farm

Comment: Thank you so much @Michael. So will i also install the sharepoint server on the DB and custom servers?

Comment: You don't need to install sharepoint on the DB servers.Custom servers, yes you need to install the sharepoint.